# Cannot send more than 300 requests in one go in azure

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

We are sending requests to Microsoft emotion API to find the emotions every second. But in a single go, we are able to send only 300 requests that is for 5 minutes. After 5 minutes, it stops sending the responses. If we start the the application again, we are able to send the requests for another 5 minutes.

Account is "Pay as you go Standard".

Thank you.

Comment: Are you saying that after 300 requests over 5 minutes, there is simply no response at all from the server?  


If that's not accurate, are you getting back any http status codes?

Comment: Our problem is with cooling period of cogntive service which we are observing after consecutive 300 requests (approx). The service just stop responding after sending 300 requests which is running per second. We are not getting any  error code , it just stops giving result

Comment: 1) Are you able to reproduce this from any other location?  This simply doesn't seem right.

2) Do you have Fiddler traces/Network traces showing this behavior?  

3) My best advice is to open a support case with Microsoft so that we can review your subscription and find the actual calls that are being made.  This is more involved than Stack Overflow can handle.

Comment: Thank you so much for reply. It has been resolved. We had ticked a option which was responsible for this.

Comment: Can you explain what option that was?  I am unaware of it.